# How to Adjust the second div

Tags: css

I have two Div

http://jsfiddle.net/KuX3G/

**future**

|--- **futureBorderL**
|
|--- **futureBorderR**

The **futureBorderR** Div is not up to the line, which is the right one.

Plz suggest.

Thanks!!!

Comment: huh! that doesnt make sense to me.... can you try to expand on your question

Answer (score 1):

add `float:left` for  `#futureBorderL`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/KuX3G/2/

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you are trying to have two divs side by side

```
<div style="float:left; width: 150px;">Left</div>
<div style="margin-left: 150px;">Right</div>
```

Comment: `<span>`?? Why someone to do that?

Comment: try to validate a code like `<span><div>text here</div></span>`. It's not valid because block elements like `div` is not valid to place them within an inline element like `span`. So you can't base a whole structure, like OP's example shows, on spans.

Comment: ar yes! haha. ok forget spans :)